# Insert if pseudo doesn't exists

Tags: php, mysql

I started to learn PHP and mysql. I want to check if the pseudo already exists in my database. If it is, don't do anything, if not insert.
This is the code that i use:

```
if (isset( $_POST['pseudo'])) {

    $sel = $bdd -> prepare('SELECT pseudo FROM ajax WHERE pseudo = :pseudo');
    $sel -> bindParam(':pseudo', $_POST['pseudo'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $sel->execute();
    while ( $data = $sel->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        if ( $data['pseudo'] == $_POST['pseudo'] ) {
            echo 'This pseudo already exist, please change it';
        } else {
            $insert = $bdd -> prepare('INSERT INTO ajax(id, nom, prenom, pseudo) VALUES(NULL, :nom, :prenom, :pseudo)');
            $insert->bindParam(':nom', $_POST['nom']);
            $insert->bindParam(':prenom', $_POST['prenom']);
            $insert->bindParam(':pseudo', $_POST['pseudo']);
            $insert->execute(); 
        }
    }
}
```

I need your help because it doesn't both check or insert!

Comment: does it not work? what is your question or your problem?

Comment: It doesn't do anything, I edit it! :)

Comment: You don't actually have to iterate over a result. Just use `count` to check if you have a result. Otherwise nothing matches your Query and thus you do not have that pseudo in your Database and you can do your insert. Read the Mysqli Documentation to learn how to use `count` : http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

Comment: I used [PDOStatement::rowCount()](http://www.php.net/manual/fr/pdostatement.rowcount.php) and when the pseudo exists it return 1 if not nothing happen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem probably appears when your pseudo already exists.
This leads your SELECT to not return any Results. Without results your while block is never entered because `$data = $sel->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)` returns `null` which is casted to `false`.

You don't actually have to iterate over a result anyway.

Just use `count` to check if you have a result. Otherwise nothing matches your Query and thus you do not have that pseudo in your Database and you can do your insert.

Read the Mysqli Documentation to learn how to use `count` : php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

Comment: It runs, i replace while() with if(). If($data = $sel->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {echo 'Already exists';} else {//insert syntax}

Comment: @RadonirinaMaminiaina Still, using `count` or `num_rows` would be a more delight way of doing it i guess since you do not actually need the resultset :-|#